# Upload file from applet to Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, applet

In my application I am running an applet to scan a picture from client. I need to upload the scanned file to the server then to database.  I can upload the file by submitting a form in JSP, but I need the applet to post the file to URL.

Any hep would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/spring/upload");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

    DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(
        connection.getOutputStream());
    printout.write(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("c:\\img_khar.jpg")));

    printout.flush();
    printout.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream()));

    String decodedString;

    while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(decodedString);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: ..What is your question?

Comment: i have this code to send the file and i want to receive the file on Spring mvc. but this doesnt work. Could you help me what i miss?

Comment: Did it occur to you that *"doesnt work"* is almost completely useless at describing the actual problem, and will almost certainly not result in someone providing a fix.  We can't fix things by magic.

Comment: Sorry i couldnt explain the problem very good. I finally figured it out. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use http client from apache for cases like this.  They provide a MultipartEntity class that can be added to your HttpPost.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html